# What is the common perception of 藪医者? Or how to tackle with amiguity here?

Tags: meaning, expressions

In a spoken story (action in late-Edo, early-Meiji period) there was a passage describing someone's life situation (a street peddler selling dubious medicines) using the following words:

> この人は藪医者と言いたいが、
>   **は(っ)ちごぐらいでさか(い)やりません**。

The meaning of the second part was unclear. At the time I was trying to analyze what was being said, a native Japanese speaker claimed it was 破竹ぐらいで食べられません however I could no confirm any other metaphorical usage of 破竹 except for [破竹]{はちく}の[勢]{いきお}い. And this sentence did not make much sense to me.

Now something made me revisit the notes and I started to wonder about this comparison. Even if the second part is incomprehensible, what might be the reason to compare someone (selling snake oil) to a quack? They sound similar, no use for が.

Is there any preconception of 藪医者? That you could negate to describe someone's situation? Like "rich" for example (I doubt though). As I understand the concept of saying と言いたいが here is to express something in line with "If I called him X, it would mean he is rich, but he was not."

Even if I have no way to get back to the original story, how to tackle with what I have? Are there any clues in either in the meaning of 藪医者 or the phrase wording?

Comment: ビデオか、音源かなにか、あります？

Comment: @Shoko It's complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess would be that it is some kind of variation of:

> この人は藪医者と言いたいが、
>   **筍{たけのこ}ぐらいでしかありません**
>   *I'd like to say he is a “bamboo thicket” doctor (= quack),*
>   *but he's barely a bamboo shoot.*

[筍医者](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/136156/meaning/m0u/) is a humorous term for a person who is so utterly incompetent they cannot even be called a fully-grown quack. I think it's safe to say that this term [was in existence](http://www.gakken.co.jp/kagakusouken/spread/oedo/05/kaisetsu1.html) during the time frame of your story.

Comment: Wow! やぶ医者にも至らない... So the perception of a quack was not that negative, at least their skills were recognised to a degree. Is there any chance for さかい being Kansai-ben here? さかい for ので makes no sense followed by ありません, right?

Comment: @macraf I clarified my post in case it was misleading. タケノコ医者 is even more incompetent than a やぶ医者. As for the Kansai-ben possibilities, Choco or l'électeur will be of better help…

Comment: That was super-clear from the beginning and I just wanted to say I was impressed. Anyway, that was exactly what I was asking for ("how to deal with ambiguity"). To disparage a person 藪医者 was used here as a positive point of reference; although used stand-alone it would be highly negative in reference to a doctor.

Comment: @macraf Ok, I see what you're saying now. I enjoy your laser-sharp logical approach to things!

Comment: Could 八竹 serve as a synonym of 筍?

Comment: @macraf Never heard of it, but I guess so. Maybe older or more cultured people are familiar with it. Could also be regional thing. http://foodslink.jp/syokuzaihyakka/syun/vegitable/hachiku.htm

Comment: Further following your idea, I wonder if a small 藪 could be is described as 「small bambooしか栄えません」. Would 栄える fit such negative comparison?